# Make callback wait till function returns result in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

There is an array of files that will have to be processed. Files may be of different types, so there are different functions doing the processing. I expect to go through all files, collect logs while at it, and in the end return a variable where all the logs are stored.

The code:

```
var file_list = req.body.filelist.split(','); //array of filenames
var logs = []; //logs about the file processing will be stored here

//iteration through each file
async.forEach(file_list , function(file_from_list , callback){
    if(file_is_type1(file_from_list)){
        process_filetype_1(file_from_list);
        callback(null);
    }
    else if(file_is_type1(file_from_list)){
        process_filetype_2(file_from_list);
        callback(null);
    }
    else{
        logs.push("Unknown file type");
    }
},function(error, result){
     return res.status(200).send({message: import_log});
});
```

There are two different functions with differences in logic that process the files. It is a complicated code, but runs smoothly and each action is performed at the right time. Here is an abstraction of one of the functions:

```
function process_filetype_1(file_from_list){
    async.auto({
        dosth_1: function(callback) {
            //logic implementation
        },
        dosth_2: ['dosth_1', function(callback) {
            //logic implementation
        }]
    }, function(error, results) {
        return results;
    });
}
```

**What happens:** all files are processed, but callbacks inside the iteration don't wait for the function to finish execution. Therefore the response is send before files have finished processing

**Why it happens:** calling process_filetype_1(file_from_list) and callback(null) is asynchronous. callback(null) finishes first, all files are iterated, the execution flow goes to sending the response. In the meanwhile the functions are still executing.

**How to fix it:** Haven't figured it out. Ideally, callback would wait for the functions to return their respective values (and finish executing) before returning null.

**What cannot be done:** using timers to make callback wait. The number of files being processed could be from 1 to hundreds, and there is no limit in size. The amount of time it may take to process each file is unknown.

**What I have tried:** returning callbacks when the function finishes executing. Assigning the function's return value to a variable (ex. test) and doing callback(test). Neither one worked.

Comment: Promises are how I usually deal with this. Not sure if you are using es6

https://www.datchley.name/es6-promises/

Comment: Upvoted. Nicely formulated question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like:

```
if(file_is_type1(file_from_list)){
   process_filetype_1(file_from_list, callback);
}
```

and then process_filetype_1 would look something like:

```
function process_filetype_1(file_from_list, callback){
    async.auto({
        dosth_1: function(cb) {
            //logic implementation
        },
        dosth_2: ['dosth_1', function(cb) {
            //logic implementation
        }]
    }, function(error, results) {
        if(error) { callback (error); 
        } else {
        callback(results); 
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use callback-style code then any function which makes calls that take callbacks must *itself* take a callback function:

```
function process_filetype_1(file_from_list, cb) {
    async.auto({
        dosth_1: function(callback) {
            //logic implementation
        },
        dosth_2: ['dosth_1', function(callback) {
            //logic implementation
        }]
    }, function(error, results) {
        cb(error, results);
    });
}
```

Since your function doesn't seem to do anything you can just chain through:

```
function process_filetype_1(file_from_list, cb) {
    async.auto({
        dosth_1: function(callback) {
            //logic implementation
        },
        dosth_2: ['dosth_1', function(callback) {
            //logic implementation
        }]
    }, cb);
}
```

An alternative is to use the Promise system possibly in conjunction with `async`/`await` to help detangle this code. I've found they're considerably easier to work with, especially with complicated flow control situations.